# reloadData not triggering cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with one UITableView in it. The table view holds a list of favorites that can be changed by other parts of the app. I am using NSNotificationCenter to trigger the table view's reloadData method. The table view has an outlet declared as follows:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *faveTableView;
```

and synthesized as follows:

```
@synthesize faveTableView;
```

The delegate and datasource properties of the table view are set in the view controller's viewDidLoad as follows:

```
[self.faveTableView setDataSource:self];
[self.faveTableView setDelegate:self];
```

The NSNotificationCenter causes the following method to fire:

```
-(void)reloadNotificationReceived{
    [self loadData];
    [self.faveTableView reloadData];
}
```

loadData updates the data source which is NSMutableArray of managed objects and is working as it should.

When the view controller loads, cellForRowAtIndexPath is fired as it should be. However, when the notification is received, reloadNotificationReceived is fired and two of the table view delegate methods (numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView) ARE fired. However, cellForRowAtIndexPath is NOT fired. numberOfRowsInSection IS returning the correct number of items.

Can anyone offer up a reason why cellForRowAtIndexPath does not get fired here? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns one, and `numberOfRowsInSection:` returns zero?

Comment: Are you sure numberOfRowsInSection returns a count larger than 0?

Comment: What is the number of rows you are returning?

Comment: If your table is not visible when the notification is sent, the runtime may skip updating the table altogether. Could that be the case in your app?

Comment: Yes, numberOfRows is returning the correct number of items. I will edit the original post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows you are returning is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have set the delegate/datasource of the tableview to your controller in the storyboard/xib, but you haven't wired up the "faveTableView" tableview  `IBOutlet` of the the controller... If the del/datasource are set, then the it will successfully get data from the controller, but without the `IBOutlet` being set, the `self.faveTableView` will remain nil and hence `[self.faveTableView reloadData]` won't do anything. Put a breakpoint in your `viewDidLoad` and check whether the `self.faveTableView` is not nil...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong on this but if the delegate/datasource were not correctly set, the table view would not load data on its initial load. However, when loading the view initially, everything works

Comment: As I wrote "you have set the delegate/datasource".. so yes, we are on the same page.. what I'm saying is perhaps the IBOutlet self.faveTableView hasn't been set.

Also note:

[self.faveTableView setDataSource:self];
[self.faveTableView setDelegate:self];

will do nothing if the IBOutlet hasn't been wired up, which is why I suggested that the delegate/datasource had been wired up from storyboard/xib

Comment: Nope, I've verified that they are definitely wired up in the stroryboard

Comment: have you checked that self.faveTableView is not nil ?

Comment: No, self.faveTableView is not nil